# Centered dodecahedral number

Tags: geometry, real-numbers

Hello my question is how continues a dodecahedral number, continues in 13? or 33? and what number follows from the right number?

PD: (I don't talk english, so sorry if I have errors)

Comment: The centered dodecahedral numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A005904 and it looks like 33 is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centered dodecahedral numbers are tabulated at [oeis.org/A005904](http://oeis.org/A005904) and the formula $a(n) = (2n+1)(5n^2+5n+1)$ is given there. The first five terms are given as $1, 33, 155, 427, 909$.

Comment: I saw it and the only thing that I don't understand is why continues in 33 and not in 13?

Comment: If you had already seen it then you should have included that information in the body of your question. Anyway, there are some references on the oeis page, aren't there? Have you followed them up?

Comment: There is a different formula given on page 135 of Deza and Deza, Figurate Numbers (possibly available at Google Books). The formula given there leads to the sequence 1, 21, 95, 259, ..., given by $(2n-1)(3n^2-3n+1)$.

Comment: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1094275&tstart=477 is part of a discussion that might interest you.

Comment: @Malthael You asked "Why?" The reason is that "centered" polyhedra are concentric hollow shells. Imagine {a single cube of length 1 (1 point so far), add a cube shell of length 2 (8 new points) = 9, then length 3 (3^3-1=26) = 35, length 4 (4^3-8=56) = 91, ...}. That holds for tetrahedra and octahedra. I don't know why it then changes to dual figures, but for regular [non-rhombic] dodecahedra, consider icosahedral OEIS A005902: {length 1 (1 point), plus shell length 2 (12 new points) = 13, length 3 (12+ 30 mid-edge =42) = 55, length 4 (12+2*30+ 20 center of faces =92) = 147, ...}.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The alternative sequence that you name in your comment is https://oeis.org/A193218 (noted here for future readers).